# Different tab indent settings in different modes

Tags: emacs, whitespace, indentation

I'm currently using `whitespace-cleanup` in my save hook. Using `indent-tabs-mode`, I'm able to save files without any tabs.

All is well, I don't want tabs in my files. But.

Makefiles do need tabs. That is my problem. How do I change my settings for makefile-mode?

I tried to `setq` either `indent-tabs-mode` (the doc says it becomes buffer-local) or `whitespace-style`, it does not work.

Comment: I have indent-tabs-mode set to "t" and whitespace-style set to (face tabs spaces trailing lines space-before-tab newline indentation empty space-after-tab space-mark tab-mark newline-mark), and it's working for me. If you have them set similarly, I'm not sure what else could be going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem, and it seems that this is a bug in Emacs (as of 24.2). Try this, using the following `.emacs`:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'whitespace-cleanup)
```

If you open a file, save it, and then open a Makefile, you'll have the problem you described. But if you open a Makefile first, save it, and *then* open another type of file, you'll have the opposite problem: 8 spaces will be replaced by tabs.

The problem is that `indent-tabs-mode` is buffer-local, but in `whitespace.el` it is set to a regular variable called `whitespace-indent-tabs-mode`. Hence, the first value that's seen is the one that counts.

Here's another workaround that solves some other problems too. Add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(defadvice whitespace-cleanup (around whitespace-cleanup-indent-tab
                                      activate)
  "Fix whitespace-cleanup indent-tabs-mode bug"
  (let ((whitespace-indent-tabs-mode indent-tabs-mode)
        (whitespace-tab-width tab-width))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: thanks! I did not know defadvice. It seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

OK, my bad. Files were loaded before changing the mode.

The following code works fine, provided it is loaded in the .emacs before opening any file (I have my own project manager which re-opens last files).

```
(defun my-tabs-makefile-hook ()
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t))
(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook 'my-tabs-makefile-hook)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found for whitespace is [ethan-wspace](https://github.com/glasserc/ethan-wspace). It cleans up any whitespace that you made dirty yourself but leaves other whitespace intact.

It works for tabs in makefiles and avoids the messy diff problem where there are lots of diff lines that are just whitespace changes